# How can I do two columns layout with flexbox and same spacing between items in column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Hello!** Can you help me? I'm trying to do two column layout with same spacing between items in same column.
[image: Two columns layout]

```css
.flex {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
}

.item {
  width: 45%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: navy;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  height: 210px;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 500px;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  height: 360px;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  height: 400px;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for every good advice & your help!

Comment: Do you have any code you could share?

Comment: Can you update your question to include your HTML and CSS please

Comment: What do you mean by spacing? Between the columns or between the items in the columns. Also, show us the code you’ve done to work towards this.

Comment: *Added code & image

Comment: Confused by the use of flexbox here. All the boxes have a specific height on them, is that just for the demo?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts) instead of `flexbox`. In this situation, there's no need to implement a flexible box layout.  You're not trying to maintain identical sizes or adjust for any odd alignment.

```css
.flex
{
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.item{
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: navy;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.item:nth-child(1){height: 210px;}
.item:nth-child(2){height: 500px;}
.item:nth-child(3){height: 360px;}
.item:nth-child(4){height: 400px;}
.item:nth-child(5){height: 150px;}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a way to use percentages for the column gap.  It uses `0px` `column-gap` and a negative margin on the container to adjust for the excess margins on the left and right.

```css
.flex
{
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
  margin: 0 -1.25%;
}

.item{
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: navy;
  break-inside: avoid;
  margin: 0 2.5% 5%;
}

.item:nth-child(1){height: 210px;}
.item:nth-child(2){height: 500px;}
.item:nth-child(3){height: 360px;}
.item:nth-child(4){height: 400px;}
.item:nth-child(5){height: 150px;}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I delete space over the second element? And how I can set grap to 5%? I try set grap to 0 and use left&right margins but i want space only between elements.

Comment: @trip1e I've updated my answer with an approach to simulating percentage based column gaps.

Comment: Thanks you, but how I can delete space over the first or second elemnt?

Comment: @trip1e I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you clarify?  What space are you referring to?

Comment: This space over the element :( I don't know how to fix it.

https://imgur.com/DEIHUEt